# typescript привести к типу

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript, vuex, nuxt.js

Использую typescript во vuex, и есть такой код в экшене

```
import { ActionContext, ActionTree } from 'vuex'
import { UserModel, UserState } from '~/types/user'
import { RootState } from '~/types'

interface UserActionContext extends ActionContext<UserState, RootState> {}

/**
 * Actions
 */
export const actions: ActionTree<UserState, RootState> = {
    fetchUsers({ commit, state }: UserActionContext, payload) {
        return this.$axios
            .$get('/v1/users', {
                params: {
                    page: state.meta.page,
                    limit: state.meta.limit,
                    orderby: [state.meta.orderBy],
                    ...payload
                }
            })
            .then(({ data }: { data: Array<UserModel> }) => {
                commit('ADD_USERS', data)
            })
            .catch(({ message }) => {
                commit('ADD_NOTIFICATION', message, { root: true })
            })
    }
}

export default actions
```

Так вот, data, может быть чем угодно, что в корне не верно, тк у меня прописан интерфейс с данными и их типами, но он полностью игнорируется... Как решить эту проблему вообще?

Comment: никак :) только вручную проверять что пришло на самом деле

Comment: @Grundy О_о типа на каждую строчку писать typeof? или как? и почему никак, с чем это связано?

Comment: Это связано с тем, что TS компилируется в JS. А данные вам приходят во время исполнения кода и там может быть что угодно. Откуда компилятору TS знать, что через год вам сервер отправит неверные данные?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko О_о ужс))) то есть мне писать класс, и в классе в конструкторе на каждую стрчоку писать проверку? только так? как люди это решают вообще

Comment: Никак не решают. Мы верим ответу от АПИ. Почему у вас там может быть что угодно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я привык просто все типизировать)))

Comment: Типизируйте, кто вам мешает? Можете даже какой нибудь json schema прикрутить. Но не ожидайте, что компилятор TS будет вам данные проверять :) Так почему у вас там может быть что угодно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дак кто его знает)) но лучше проверить всегда

Comment: А что будете делать, если вдруг АПИ начало не то присылать? Ну прям вообще не то?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну вообще тесты на беке не должны такое допустить))